# Angularjs ngRepeat does not iterate, shows only data from first record

Tags: angularjs

I am not very experienced with angular and I just can't figure out why is my code behaving like this.. I have a controller, that gets data from a factory and a modal to display it. It returns the right data, according to the id it passes, but after on ng-repeat it loads the data for the first record only or nothing:

`

```
<div ng-controller="TokensCtrl"><a href="#tokensModal" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="getTokens(child.ChildId)" ng-model="child.ChildId">Get Tokens{{child.ChildId}}</a>
                <div id="tokensModal" class="modal fade tokens" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h3>Tokens:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <ul ng-repeat='token in tokens'>
                            <li><input value={{token}} /></li>
                        </ul>{{tokens}} <!--the first record set of tokens on every iteration -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

`the controller, that returns the right data:`

```
app.controller('TokensCtrl',
    function ($scope, tokens) {
        $scope.status;
        $scope.test = 'testing';

        $scope.getTokens = function (id) {
            console.log(id + "controller");
            tokens.getTokens(id)
                .success(function (tokens) {
                    $scope.tokens = tokens;
                    console.log($scope.tokens);// here i can see it returns the right set of tokens
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = "Unable to get tokens: " + error.message;
                })
        }
    }
)
```

`

I assume it might be some silly mistake, but I just can't see it.. or not

Comment: You might need a `$scope.$apply()` in that success callback, try putting it where you currently have `console.log`.

Comment: nope, this did not work "$digest already in progress"

Comment: Hmm well I don't know if it would cause your issue but you probably want to move `ng-repeat='token in tokens'` to the `li`, right now you are creating an unordered list for each token.

Comment: create a jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: when I check the scope with the chrome Angularjs plugin it gives me: getTokens: undefined, but the data is there:
tokens: [
435455,
545343,
545466,
903003
]

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the ng-repeat directive in the **li** tag instead of **ul**.